# SQL - Incorrect integer value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am currently working on an Airflow project and one of the dags is triggering this SQL query:

```
select CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) as datum,
    sum(convert(int, fertig))/convert(float, count(*)) as servicegrad,
    count(*) as position, 
    sum(Anzahl) as positionsdetails, 
    sum(convert(int, fertig)) as fertig, CASE
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger1%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger2%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger3%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger4%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger5%') THEN 'lager1'
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger6%' or Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger7%' or  
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger8%' or Empfänger LIKE '%9%') THEN 'lager2'
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE N'%empfänger10%' or
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger11%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger11%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger12%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger13%') THEN 'Lager3'


        ELSE 'lager4' 
    END as typ from wa left join (
        select count(*) as Anzahl, WaID from wadetails 
        group by WaID
    ) as wad on wad.WaID = wa.ID
where (CONVERT(DATE, ABTermin) > CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day, -1,GETDATE())) 
and
CONVERT(DATE, ABTermin) < CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day, 1,GETDATE())))
group by 
    CASE
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger1%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger2%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger3%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger4%' or 
            Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger5%') THEN 'lager1'
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger6%' or Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger7%' or  
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger8%' or Empfänger LIKE '%9%') THEN 'lager2'
        WHEN (Empfänger LIKE N'%empfänger10%' or
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger11%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger11%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger12%' or 
        Empfänger LIKE '%empfänger13%') THEN 'Lager3'


        ELSE 'lager4'
    END
```

The query is supposed to transfer data from a Mssql database to a Mysql database. But when it runs I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'lager4' for column 'fertig' at row 1")
```

I think I understand what the error means, the value 'lager4' should be written into column typ but is written into column fertig instead. But I can't seem to find the problem in query that leads to the error.

Comment: *I can't seem to find the problem in querry that leads to the error.* `convert(int, fertig)`

Comment: So the query in your question is selecting data from SQL Server but what code is inserting that into MySQL? Seems like the columns are misaligned so it's trying to insert the `typ` column from SQL Server into `fertig` in MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Hallo, thank you for your answers. In the mssql fertig is bit value and I'm trying to sum them to count how many are finished.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The column beeing misaligned makes sense. I guess I would have to reorder the Mysql table or can I change the querry to acomodate the misalignment? I'm sorry for all these basic questions, but I'm knew to working with Databases and sql

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question but it will suggest where to look.

If you are getting a MySQL error, then the code is running fine in SQL Server.  The issue is however you are inserting the values into MySQL.

Happily, that just means that you need to look at the `SELECT` clause.  you need to look at the types of the columns in MySQL and figure out which ones are `int`s.

Then, you have an issue with the conversion.  Possibilities are:

- `datum`
- `fertig`
- `Anzal`
- `typ`

When you know which of these columns are integers, you can investigate further.

Comment: Hallo, thank you for your answer. I looked up the types : `datum` is date , `fertig` is int(11), `typ` is varchar(45) and `Anzahl` is not a column in the Mysql. I'll follow your hints and take a look at the SELECT clause and the conversion. I also had not notice that `Anzahl` was not a column in the mysql so maybe thats what caused the issue.

Comment: @bayardim . . . The columns in the incorrect order could also be an issue.  You should look at the `insert` to see the explicit column ordering used for the `insert`.